# How to create a dynamic bundle product from frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to create a dynamic bundle product from frontend?

E.g.: Let's say that we have- vases, each vase = product And flowers, each flower = product

I need to allow the user to choose multiple flower in one vase and when the customer checkout the selected vase and its follower will be a one order.

How can I do that in magento 2.1?